# How to get junctions to work in WSL1 on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

This might be best explained with an example:

- I just bought a new NVMe drive that I want to mount as `C:\temp`. I do not want to mount this NVMe  as `D:` (or any other letter drive).
- After all this mounting setup is completed, I want to navigate from WSL1 (running Ubuntu 22.x) to my NVMe via terminal/console commands.

How can I make this happen?

I tried using junction via Computer Management, but I cannot navigate to this drive inside Ubuntu. I get an `input/output error` when I tried to `cd` to the NVMe drive.

[image: computer management/disk management screenshot]

Comment: Hmmm - It's working for me on Windows 11 (also tried on 10) with a WSL1 instance of both Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.  I just took a drive that was mounted in Windows as `G:`, removed the drive letter in Disk Management, and assigned it to `..\temp\gdrive` inside my Windows profile directory.  I was then able to navigate to it through WSL1 using `cd /mnt/c/Users/ntd/temp/gdrive` and see its contents.  The location you mounted it is a folder on the `C:` drive, I'm assuming, right?  And you are able to navigate to it from PowerShell and/or CMD?